# Proof of a coprimes property in a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I don't know how to prove well that if D is an UFD and $a,b\in D$ coprimes then if $a\mid bc\Rightarrow a\mid c$.  I've tried to put the definitions but I don't know how to conclude that $a\mid c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

The uniqueness, up to a unit factor, of factorisation of elements of $D$ into prime factors shows a prime factorisation of $bc$ is obtained multiplying a prime factorisation of $b$ and a prime factorisation of $c$. You can proceed by induction on the number $r$ of  prime factors of $a$:

If $r=1$, the ideal $(a)$ is prime and the hypothesis says $bc\in(a)$, but $b\notin (a)$, so by definition, $c\in (a)$.

*Induction step*: if $r>1$, write $a=pa'$, where $p$ is one of the prime factors of $a$, and $a'$ has $r-1$ prime. factors. Note that no prime factor of $a$ (hence of $a'$) divides $b$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Talking about the second paragraph, why it isn't enough to say that if $c\in\left(a\right)\Rightarrow\exists x\in D$ that $c=ax$ so $a\mid c$?

Comment: The 2nd paragraph is the inductive step?

Comment: Oh now I see, okay, thanks!